# Can a nested file access functions that sit in the parent file in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Imagine I have a file in Classic ASP called parent.asp and another called child.asp.

parent.asp has a function called IsActive().

Can child.asp (which is included in parent.asp through the include command) access the IsActive() function?

I wanted to ask before doing any work, cause this project I'm working on can use a good tidying up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the file is included before you try to call it.

Comment: You mean as long as the function is defined before the include statement?

Comment: Nerp, the function should be hoisted so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: <!--#include file="parent.asp"--> needs to appear in child.asp before you call the function. The function is defined in parent.asp.

Comment: The parent defines the function in line 1. Then includes child.asp in line 2. Then child.asp can use the function defined in parent.